# How to save the data in the workbook without the need to open it?

Tags: vba, excel

i currently need some edit on my code to prevent it from opening but not very sure which code to replace it. So here is my code

```
Sub CopyPasteForm()

Dim Name As String, Age As Integer, Class As String, Diploma As String, 
ContactNo As String, Hobby As String, Address As String, wkbook As Workbook
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Name = Range("B4")
Age = Range("B6")
Class = Range("B8")
Diploma = Range("B10")
ContactNo = Range("B15")
Hobby = Range("B17")
Address = Range("B19")

Set wkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\database.xlsx")
Worksheets("sheet1").Select
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select
RowCount = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0) = Name
.Offset(RowCount, 2) = Age
.Offset(RowCount, 3) = Class
.Offset(RowCount, 4) = Diploma
.Offset(RowCount, 5) = ContactNo
.Offset(RowCount, 6) = Hobby
.Offset(RowCount, 7) = Address
End With
wkbook.Save

End Sub
```

i know that

```
Set wkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\database.xlsx")
```

needs to change but i've no idea how to set the workbook from the directory without using 'open'

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/18857-adding-data-closed-workbook-without-opening.html

Comment: You can't write data to a closed workbook

Comment: @Peh so what your saying is that no matter what, i have to open the workbook?

Comment: That's correct. What you *can* do is prevent Excel from repainting itself while you're doing this, so the user doesn't even notice a flicker when the workbook is opened, written to, and then saved and closed.

Comment: Looking at your code, I think I can see what you're trying to do. I've had to build something similar myself and the best way I found to do it this is - instead of writing the data to an excel file (because what if two people try at the same time right?) it's better to append the 7 fields into a text file. This way, the file writing takes a split second each, causing much less trouble. You then build your 'Database.xlsx' to import the lines from the text file when it's opened into the right place.

Comment: Or, you use an *actual* database. Excel isn't a database engine.

Comment: Yes, that's true @Mat'sMug in a perfect world a database is the correct tool for the job - Sadly my users didn't have Access installed so I went for the next easiest approach.

Comment: lol, I said an *actual* database, not Access haha =)  SQL Server Express is free... but regardless, your users didn't need Access, just an ODBC connection to it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that should've read 'didn't have Access installed or anything else usable'. (Actually, better to read that without the word else - haha) Corporate environments eh - work with what you've got or speak to IT, wait weeks etc. etc.?